# Pytest: Running all tests based on the number of times specified in config.ini

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Here's how I have the tests written:

```
**config.ini**
idlist: 1

Class MyConfig:
   def __init__(self):
      self.id = config.idlist
      ....

**conftest.py**
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def obj()
    myobj = new MyConfig()
    yield myobj

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def get_id(obj)
    yield obj.id

**test_mytests.py**
def test_a_sample_test(get_id):
     assert get_id == 1

def test_a_sample_even test(get_id):
     assert get_id % 2 == 0
```

Now, I want to change idlist (from config.ini) to a list of numbers as below
idlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, ....]

I want to be able to automatically trigger a run to run all the tests that begins with `test_` based on the number of id's in idlist. as depicted below

```
new config.ini
idlist: id1, id2, id3, id4, ... idN

def get_id(obj):
    for anId in obj.id
        yield anId          **<--- notice that the id's change.**
```

finally the tests..

```
**test_mytests.py**
def test_a_sample_test(get_id):
     assert get_id == 1

def test_a_sample_even test(get_id):
     assert get_id % 2 == 0
```

i want to:

1. Invoke get_id to yield me a different id each time
2. The 2 tests should run for each id "yielded" by get_id, since the id changed. (basically repeat the entire test suite/session for each id)

How can I do that?

I don't know the list of ids in order to do a pytest.mark.parameterize() before each test since the id's change and are not constant.

Answer (score 0):

[`pytest.fixtures`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-fixture) takes a `params` list:

> params – an optional list of parameters which will cause multiple invocations of the fixture function and all of the tests using it.

[Examples Here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. But, my params list is not the same always. The list is determined by the environment where the tests are run. That's the reason why I need to be able to read it from a config file. I have also updated the description of my requirement.

Comment: Then read your list from the file before you call `pytest.fixtures`.

Comment: oh ok... like this?

listOfIds = readFromFile(filename)
...


@pytest.fixtures(params=listofIds)
def aGeneratorFunction(listofIds):
     for anId in listofIds:
       yield anId

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: I dont know how does that work or how to make it yield. typically in a python code you just call the generator function to continue from where it left off. in Pytest, i dont know how. once when that yield changes, i want to trigger all the tests to perform on the new id (as depicted in my description). I haven't tried that yet, and not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize) parametrizing test functions:

> The builtin `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator enables parametrization of arguments for a test function. Here is a typical example of a test function that implements checking that a certain input leads to an expected output

```py
# take the following example and adjust to your needs

import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("_id,expected", [
    (1, False),
    (2, True),
    (3, False),
])
def test_a_sample_even(_id, expected):
    assert expected == is_even(_id)
```

Comment: Thanks @DhiaTN for your input. But, In my case, the id's are in the config.ini. which ever id i specify in the list, the PyTest should be able to run all the tests for each "id's".

Comment: @prabhu unittest are meant to be simple and static, why do you need to read from fiile?

Comment: based on the id's listed, my test should be able to test multiple executions of the application. This is the newest addition. the older implementation should be retained. Also, I have updated my description. Your help is appreciated

Comment: The list is determined by the environment where the tests are run. That's the reason why I need to be able to read it from a config file and for each ID's i need to yield different result.